# load() function mongo shell for updatemany

Tags: mongodb, shell, output, load

I  am  not  getting  output when  i  call update many  via load(). My  setVerboseShell(true)

However when  i  run  the  command  explicitly in  shell prompt  it  goes  fine

```
MongoDB Enterprise > load('/opt/app/mongo/test.js') true  
MongoDB Enterprise > setVerboseShell(true)  
MongoDB Enterprise > load('/opt/app/mongo/test.js') true


MongoDB Enterprise > db.organizations.updateMany({"_id" : {$in : [ "120300007","160800001","175100009","193000031","201700008","235500001","237600001","24600001","272500006","278200081"]}},{$unset : {"asenodMigrationDetails.aseMigrationStatus" : ""}});
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 3, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In interactive mode the `mongo` shell will display the results of the last command run.

In your example, the return value of `load()` is a boolean indicating the success of loading and evaluating JavaScript from the specified file.

If you want to output results from commands in `test.js`, you need to explicitly call `print()` or `printjson()`.

Your `test.js` should instead look like:

```
var result = db.organizations.updateMany(
    {"_id" : {
        $in : ["120300007","160800001","175100009","193000031","201700008","235500001","237600001","24600001","272500006","278200081"]}},
    {$unset : {"asenodMigrationDetails.aseMigrationStatus" : ""}}
)
printjson(result);
```

For more information see [Write Scripts for the `mongo` shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo) in the MongoDB manual.

Comment: Thanks for  your  reply . Is there any other way to achieve this?. I do  not  want  to touch  the  code at  last .We  are achieving  desired result for  all operations(update insert) but  not  for  update  many

Comment: @AshadJawaid This is the expected result for the `load()` function in the `mongo` shell. If you are loading scripts from a file and want to see results of individual operations, you should explicitly output those results. For more robust I/O control I would recommend using a [supported driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/).

Comment: If you are unwilling to modify the JavaScript file but aren't set on using `load()`, another approach would be to pipe the output in via the command line, eg: `mongo hostname:port/dbname ... --quiet < test.js`. That should be equivalent to entering the lines in the interactive shell. I'd still recommend using explicit `print()`/`printjson()` statements where possible.